# Cant change config/name.json file in on pm2 instance in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have an instance on pm2 server whose id is XX. Now I want to change the config file on that instance.

Is this possible? If so then how?

I tried commands like
`export NODE_ENV="name_of_json_file"`,

```
 pm2 relaod "name_of_json_file" app.js
```

Comment: Try to replace the config file and execute pm2 restart name_of_process

Comment: what if i copied from others insatnce to my instance on server

Answer (score 0):

As [the reference](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) states, configurations are no longer reloaded:

```
pm2 startOrReload "name_of_json_file" --update-env
```